# Explain the Multi-Objective Differential Evolution

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm, differential-evolution

Can someone please explain the Multi-Objective Differential Evolution in plain words and point out its differences with the normal Differential Evolution.

An example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In normal Differential Evolution algorithms, there is only one objective to optimize. You only need to try to find a better solution.

But in a multi-objective problem, there is more than one objective. And there may be conflicts among these objectives. For example, you want to buy something. There are two targets, lower price and better quality. But they may be conflict. A lower price may mean worse quality.

So a multi-objective problem is to find a solution that satisfies all objectives to the greatest extent.